# Asp.net FormsAuthentication UserName, ID, GUID

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, guid, formsauthentication

We are using FormsAuthentication with custom MembershipProvider and custom RolePrivoder. For our Users we have a unique UserName, ID (mssql auto-key) and a GUID (all three unique).

I'm not sure which one to use for the Formsauthentication:

```
FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, false);
```

UserName, ID or GUID. Can we even store all three informations as UserData in the FormsTicket.

Per Default Asp.net takes the UserName (e.g. E-Mail adress). But I think UserName is a little bit weak if it is stored on the client. A MSSQL Auto-Key also.

So what is the securest way?

Comment: Can you explain more? You say "not sure which one to use" but, its not clear about what usage you are talking about. If you mean "the more unique value" then its obviously the GUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize and encrypt your UserData object to a string and use that for the cookie.

I answered a similar question about that here:
[Store user data in MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913664/store-user-data-in-mvc-2/5913765#5913765)